# Changing value of an input based on value of select option

Tags: php, jquery

When inserting data into my table, I need to insert the day of the week as well as the number of the day of the week so they can be displayed in chronological order. To remove any room for error, I want the number of the day of the week to be determined by a select option.

Example would be: `If select option val for .day* = Mon, .daynum* = 1`

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<select required class="form-control day<?php echo $i; ?>" name="day<?php echo $i; ?>" />

   <option  disabled value="">Day of the Week</option>
   <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
   <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
   <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
   <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
   <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
   <option value="Sat">Saturday</option>
   <option value="Sun">Sunday</option>

</select>

<input required class="form-control daynum<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" name="daynum<?php echo $i; ?>" />
```

**jQ:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.daynum1').val($('.day1 option:selected').val());

$('.day').on('change', function() {
    $('.daynum1').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});

});
```

Currently my code just gets the initial value of the first row pulled from the database and sets it to Monday.

The code I have calls all rows and lets me edit them all at once, which gives each input/select a class that is "dayx" where x is the unique id from the database.

Comment: Why don't you just change the option values to be numbers?

Comment: The information is stored in the database and when displayed must be in chronological order. I have them ordered by DayNum

Comment: Why don't you store the day numbers in the database, and translate them to names when displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the day names, and use the index as the day number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var days = ["", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
    $('.day').on('change', function() {
        $('.daynum1').val(days.indexOf($(this).val()));
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

BTW, you don't need to use `option:selected` to get the value of a `<select>`. Calling `.val()` on the `<select>` itself works.

Comment: This works and thanks for the tip for the selected business! 
Question: the page can load up to 10 separate pairs of inputs and the number at the end of the class changes. So there can be multiple rows of inputs,  but the .day and .daynum still correspond to each other based on the number at the end. 
Ex. two pairs of inputs loaded would have classes .day1 and .daynum1, and .day2 and .daynum2. How can I make sure when I change the day class that the corresponding daynum value changes too?

Comment: Since the `daynum` field is right after the `day` field, you can use `$(this).next().val(...)` instead of `$('.daynum1').val(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get value from input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.daynum1').val();

  $('.day').on('change', function() {
    $('.daynum1').val();
  });

  });
```

Comment: `.val()` with no argument retrieves the value, but you're not doing anything with the value.